# Spring Boot Role Based Security JWT

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, jwt

I'm using spring boot with Angular 2. I implemented a JWT REST endpoint for authentication. My angular 2 front end using an authentication service to send the username and password to the spring boot backend. On the backend I only want a user with an LDAP role to have access to login. I implemented the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserJWTController {

    @Inject
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;



    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authorize(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletResponse response) {


        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());

        try {
            Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> userAuthorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
            for(SimpleGrantedAuthority authCheck: userAuthorities){
                if(authCheck.toString().equals(LDAP_USER_ROLE )){
                    String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, true);
                    response.addHeader(JWTConfigurer.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + jwt);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JWTToken(jwt));
                }


            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);    


        } catch (AuthenticationException exception) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(Collections.singletonMap("AuthenticationException",exception.getLocalizedMessage()), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

The piece of code that I have a question on is:

```
Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> userAuthorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
                for(SimpleGrantedAuthority authCheck: userAuthorities){
                    if(authCheck.toString().equals(LDAP_USER_ROLE )){
                        String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, true);
                        response.addHeader(JWTConfigurer.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + jwt);
                        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JWTToken(jwt));
                    }


                }
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
```

What I'm doing is setting the role in a constant that I import called: `LDAP_USER_ROLE`

I create a collection variable to store the user authorities and use a for each loop to check if that user role is in the authorities collection. If it is, I return a JWT token, if it is not, I return a 403.

Is there a better way to do this? It works, but doesn't seem like an efficient way to check if the user possesses that role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@PreAuthorize` annotation from springboot security.

Example:
https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bfwg/rest/UserController.java#L48

Comment: This requires me to create a @preAuthorize annotation for each RequestMapping?

Comment: You can also put preAuthorize in you spring config file. For example                                                    `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");`